# Can I forward my text messages from my Android phone to a Chromebook?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms

I am coming from an iPhone and a mac book, and I am used to the idea of being able to send and receive all my texts, calls, and face times from my laptop. After making this huge switch, I am confused how anyone can consider this better. Can someone tell me if this is possible? I am not against any sort of under the table methods of making this happen. I have a Galaxy S3 and a Samsung Chromebook 2, so if Google can't do it, I'm thinking Samsung should be able to.

Answer (score 2):

MightyText: http://www.mightytext.net

and PushBullet: https://www.pushbullet.com/

are third-party apps that provide this functionality.